# Why does my Switch-statement case not fire on exact string matches?

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement

Switch Statements have betrayed me... The following switch statement does not match any of the cases and instead prints the `default` case every time.

I have tried removing the default case and added type-checks to the involved variables and it still simply does not match.
I have even retyped the case Strings manually to make sure I did not copy-paste any wrong characters. Removing the `()` characters also did not help.

The strings match 1:1 every time and the type is always `string`. These are also the last remaining cases. There were another ~ 10 cases before, but all matched fine and performed the desired action.

It would be awesome if anyone knew what is going wrong here, thank you in advance!

```
const subUniName = sub.data().university;  // Is always one of the cases, f.e.: 'Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)'

let correctUniName;

console.log('type of raw data: ' + typeof sub.data().university) // Logs string
console.log('type of raw data appended to const (same thing): ' + typeof subUniName) // Logs string
console.log('subUniName: ' + subUniName)

// Update University Name
switch (subUniName) {
    case "Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)":
        correctUniName = "Hochschule Fresenius University of Applied Sciences";
        break;
    case 'Hochschule RheinMain (Wiesbaden und Rüsselsheim)':
        correctUniName = "Hochschule RheinMain University of Applied Sciences Wiesbaden Rüsselsheim";
        break;
    case 'EBS Universität für Wirtschaft und Recht (Wiesbaden, Oestrich-Winkel)':
        correctUniName = "EBS Universität für Wirtschaft und Recht";
        break;
    case 'Hochschule Ruhr West (Mülheim, Bottrop)':
        correctUniName = "Hochschule Ruhr West University of Applied Sciences";
        break;
    case "Duale Hochschule Baden-Württemberg (Stuttgart)":
        correctUniName = "DHBW - Duale Hochschule Baden-Württemberg";
        break;
    case 'Hochschule Augsburg (HSA)':
        correctUniName = "Hochschule für angewandte Wissenschaften Augsburg - University of Applied Sciences";
        break;
    case 'Hochschule Karlsruhe - Technik und Wirtschaft':
        correctUniName = "Hochschule Karlsruhe - Technik und Wirtschaft - University of Applied Sciences";
        break;
    case 'Hochschule Westküste (Heide)':
        correctUniName = "";
        break;
    default:
        console.log(sub.data().university + ' not matched')
        break;
}
```

Here is a **live example** with the same characters returned by `sub.data().university`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3zcwdz

Here is a screenshot of the output in the terminal (running node):

[image: The Terminal Output]

**EDIT:**

Just tried adding the line `` console.log(`Does ${subUniName} match Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)? ${subUniName === "Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)"}`) ``
Which should return true once `subUniName` is `Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)`.

However it prints this:

Does Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden) match Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)? false

I am so confused right now. The Type of `subUniName` ist `string`, the characters are the exact same, no whitespace or anything - what am I missing?

**EDIT2:**

Here is a live reproduction of the issue with the data I get from `sub.data().university` stored in an array.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3zcwdz

Comment: Please show us an example output from "subUniName".

Comment: Make sure there is no leading or trailing whitespace - that is easy to overlook when making debug outputs, but will of course trip up any equal comparison.

Comment: Well the only explanation for that is that your string is not an exact match. However as you haven't included a case that does not work, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Don't depend on your eyes. There are many characters that are "non-printing" -- in other words, they don't show up on screen without a little help. Some text editors can help with that.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the terminal output and commented every log for better clarity. There are no white-spaces as far as I have seen and I have retyped all the Strings by hand. @Heteric Monkey I am using VS Code, what kind of non-printing characters are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "work-around" you can try with this mapping function:

```
// Return correct uni name.
function doUniMapping(uni) {
  uni = uni.trim();
  return uniMapping.hasOwnProperty(uni) ? 
  uniMapping[uni]: `University ${uni} not matches.`;
}
console.log(doUniMapping(subUniName));
```

Here the mapping object:

```
const uniMapping = {
  "Hochschule Fresenius (Wiesbaden)":
      "Hochschule Fresenius University of Applied Sciences",
  'Hochschule RheinMain (Wiesbaden und Rüsselsheim)':
      "Hochschule RheinMain University of Applied Sciences Wiesbaden Rüsselsheim",
  'EBS Universität für Wirtschaft und Recht (Wiesbaden, Oestrich-Winkel)':
      "EBS Universität für Wirtschaft und Recht",
  'Hochschule Ruhr West (Mülheim, Bottrop)':
      "Hochschule Ruhr West University of Applied Sciences",
  "Duale Hochschule Baden-Württemberg (Stuttgart)":
      "DHBW - Duale Hochschule Baden-Württemberg",
  'Hochschule Augsburg (HSA)':
      "Hochschule für angewandte Wissenschaften Augsburg - University of Applied Sciences",
  'Hochschule Karlsruhe - Technik und Wirtschaft':
      "Hochschule Karlsruhe - Technik und Wirtschaft - University of Applied Sciences",
  'Hochschule Westküste (Heide)':
      ""
};
```

Here a full working example with a mapping object:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-matching-uni-mapping?file=index.js

I think is better of your switch.

Next time in the question, insert a piece of code with your problem, with stackblitz or whatever you prefer.

I can't extract the output strings from your screenshot so you'll have to try it out yourself.

**EDIT:** There's a strange space character: ' ' between string name and '('.

Here a modified working example from your code, using `replace`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-matching-uni-db-strings?file=index.js

I suggest you to remove that character from your DB records.

**EDIT2:** The next time you can find these strange character with a text editor like Notepad++, in this way:
[image: Find strange invisible characters]

Comment: I tried implementing your solution, however it does not match any of the strings. I'll create a stackblitz now.

Comment: You can simply "Fork" mine with your example "subUniName" not working string.

Comment: The mapping object will have the same issue as the `switch` if the same values are used for the property names as are used `case` values...

Comment: True, but it is a better way to do a mapping (more compact and more flexible) and missing his stackblitz we cannot understand what is the character that he receives and that we do not see. When we have his stackblitz we will understand.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3zcwdz Here is an example with the exact characters I get from my database. The same example worked with characters I just added to the array manually. Just copy the `unis` Array to your example to work with the same data.

Comment: EDIT: There's a strange space character: ' ' between string name and '('.

Here a modified working example from your code, using `replace`:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-matching-uni-db-strings?file=index.js

I suggest you to remove that character from your DB records.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how it got in there and why it is only in a few of the strings... Thank you for the fix!